# Getting "invalid acl key *unresolved" after a while using Parse.com

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, synchronization

I use the [Parse.com](https://parse.com) Cloud service in my Android app to sync data between devices.

I use the app mainly offline and use the local Datastore. I sync the data by calling

```
myParseObject.save();
```

on every changed object. That works great but after some time I get the ParseRequestException

> ParseRequestException: invalid acl key *unresolved

It looks like I can't sync any more objects after that. It always throws this error until I reinstall my app.

I also don't have any restrictions defined in Parse. No ACLs and I use anonymous user login.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found [the solution reading this post on Parse.com](https://www.parse.com/questions/acl-error-with-saveeventually).

I was using anonymous users for the app. I changed that to using a single default User.

The problem was

> saveEventually will not work if an item being saved has a relation to an automatic user that has never been saved

and it seems that constellation appears at some point.